# Какое отношение камаринская имеет к комарам?

Tags: однокоренные-слова

Все знают, что есть танец комаринская, но, вот интересно, название имеет какое-то отношение к комарам или это просто совпадение? И, если имеет, то какое? Такое же, как тарантелла - к тарантулам?

Answer (score 2):

Это название одной из разновидностей русской пляски является субстантивированным прилагательным из словосочетания камаринский мужик. Предположительно прилагательное камаринский возникло от топонима Камаричи – названия одной из волостей в Орловской губернии.

В XVI—ХVII вв. волость занимала весьма обширную территорию на юге Московского государства, теперь это территория на стыке Брянской, Курской и Орловской областей.Разные варианты названия Комарицкой волости породили не одну гипотезу происхождения названия:

а) Комарицкая волость или Камаричи получили свое название  слов камара, камор, камора, комора, камера в значении 'особая комната, кладовая, хранилище, сокровищница, казна, казнохранилище', где вначале литовские и польские короли, а затем московские цари хоронили (прятали) доходы, поступавшие от владения этой волостью.

б) От каморник, каморники. Так называли людей, не имевших своих домов и живших в чужих избах и каморах. К их числу относили сторожей, истопников, работников в доме, занимавших каморки. Комарицкая волость, вследствие усиленной колонизации по укреплению южных границ Московского государства, проводимой особенно активно по велению царя Ивана Грозного, была краем бездомников, бродяг. Волость «кишела каморниками, и им, вероятно, она обязана своим названием»

в) От характера песни: поющие ее прыгают, как комары».

г) «Комариная» основа в некоторых формах названия волости бытует и сейчас. Это народная этимология, согласно которой название получено волостью по признаку обилия в местности комаров»  Но: «При чем тут какие-то комары, когда речь идет прямо о своеобразном народном герое, об исторической личности"?

д) От река Марица, некогда очень полноводной, а ныне обмелевшей и превратившейся в ручей.

http://family-history.ru/material/onomastics/toponimika/toponimika_42.html